# How to read data from a CSV file and use it in a PUT request

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work out a script, which will read a column from a CSV file one by one and use it in a PUT request. The column data from the CSV file will be uploaded to a site via API.

Comment: http://papaparse.com/

Comment: Your question is *far* too broad. You need to narrow down the specific problem you are having. Is it reading data from a file? Reading data from a URL? Parsing CSV? Restructuring the data to fit the API? Creating a PUT request? What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
function sendResultsToServer(results) {
  console.log('submitting: ', results.data);
  fetch('/your/api/endpoint/', {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: results.data
  });
}

function submit() {
  var file = document.getElementById('csvFileInput').files[0];
  Papa.parse(file, {complete: sendResultsToServer});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.2.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<input id="csvFileInput" type="file">
<button onClick="submit()">Submit</button>
```